# Can I parse a DOM element after the document has loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, select

I have a select-box which I style using jQuery and [**chosen**](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).
But because the script executes after `$(document).ready`, there's a split second where the original select-box is displayed, especially if the connection is slow.

Because I put the select-box inside a table, there would already be an allocated space for it so it wouldn't hurt the render of the page.

Can I manipulate this element into parsing after the page is loaded? This way, the original style of the select-box wouldn't show.
Is this even the correct approach to go about this issue?

Example Code:

```
<div id="header">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:25%"></td>
            <td style="width:50%"></td>
            <td style="width:25%"><select class="chosen">
                    <option>Option 1</option>
                    <option>Option 2</option>
                    <option>Option 3</option>
                </select></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".chosen").chosen({width: "75%", disable_search: true});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: If the script is directly below the table as you show, then don't use `.ready()`. Just run the `$(".chosen").chosen(...` code immediately. That'll reduce the latency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would tackle the situation. By default in your CSS you could set `.chosen` to `display: none;`.

Then you could write your JavaScript like this.

```
var sChosen = $(".chosen");
sChosen.chosen({width: "75%",disable_search: true});
sChosen.show(); // show the element after chosen() has taken effect
```

**UPDATE**

CSS

```
.chosen {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var sChosen = $(".chosen");
sChosen.chosen({width: "75%",disable_search: true});
sChosen.css('visibility', 'visible'); // show the element after chosen() has taken effect
```

Comment: That's an idea. But with this approach, `visibility: hidden` would be more appropriate.

Comment: It depends on the effect you're going for and what your users expect, but I think you make a really good point. It'll show the user that something should be there.